# Can I change the platform version of an android app after creating it?

Tags: java, android

I am just learning about android app development and have created my first app which is a relatively simple app with a link to a gallery of images and some text pages. I created this using the 1.5 platform as it seemed sensible to make it backwards compatible. I've been testing it on 3.0 and it comes up tiny on the screen and I have since learnt I need to use supports-screens and other related commands to allow variable screen support which from what i read is only available in 1.6 and above. As a result I need to change the app platform to 1.6 or above and my questions are as follows:

1) Am I able to just go to project properties and change the platform version tickbox to a newer one (in this case 1.6)? As I tried this with the project but the supports-screens tag still gives an error (which it doesn't when I create a brand new project)?

2) What version should I be creating it in these days for ideal backwards compatibility but able to use most desirable features? I understand 1.6 includes a lot of the newer functionality but according to http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html only about 4% of people are using less than 2.1 so is it better to just code using 2.1 (assuming I want to target mobiles and tablets)?

Thanks so much for your help as ever,

Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html#uses).  It explains how you can go about changing your AndroidManifest.xml to specify which version of the SDK to use.  You may also need to update `default.properties` to point the `target` to the proper api value.
2. This really depends on what you want to do.  If you require something from 2.1 or 3.0, then I think you need to go with that.  But if you can get by using just 1.6 and still have all the functionality that you need/want, then I would definitely recommend using 1.6.